# How to do filtering by select in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have array of object in AngularJS as:

```
var arr = [{type : 1, name : 'Bbc'}];
```

Also I have select list:

```
<select ng-model="type">
<option value="1">Select</option>
</select>
```

How I can filter object in ng-repeat by selected option from select?

Comment: Check angular's documentation regarding filters: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter ... you can use functions as filters, so you could define a function in your scope and check the type model there and return based on the comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly I would do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <p>Select type to filter:</p>
    <select ng-model="filterTypes" ng-options="item.type for item in types"></select>
    <div ng-repeat="type in types | filter:filterTypes">
        <p>{{type.name}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.types =
    [{type : 1, name : 'Bbc'},
     {type : 2, name: 'Bcc'},
     {type : 3, name: 'Bac'}         
    ];
}
```

Here is a fiddle if you want to see the results: http://jsfiddle.net/fsalin/3oLv66ff/8/

Comment: But if there is filter yet? Can I use two filters? But input field and select list?

Comment: Yes you can use multiple filters. I have created a fiddle showing how to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/fsalin/3oLv66ff/21/

Comment: To use multiple filters you just have to add additional filter attributes separated with "|" to the ng-repeat directive and map these to ng-models. See fiddle for clarification.